# imagebutton inside a listview

Tags: android, imagebutton

How can i manupilate the properties of an ImageButton inside a listview i mean the image and enabling and disabling the button ?

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); 
    TextView retail_price = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Retail_price);
    TextView deal_price = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Deal_price);
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Time); 
    ImageButton imgB = ( ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    TextView participants = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Particpant);  
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); 

    HashMap<String, String> otherdeals = new HashMap<String, String>();
    otherdeals = data.get(position);

   imgB.setImageResource(R.drawable.boutonachete);
```

Comment: You already asked exact the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795418/conditionally-change-imagebutton-image/ and you got helpful responses

Answer (score 0):

For enabling/disabling, u mean: imgB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)/imgB.setVisibility(View.GONE) ?
To manipulate the image u can retrieve its drawable and do whatever u want with it: imgB.getDrawable()